# FailedPreconditionError: Could not find variable weights_15. | Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

**I'm learning about linear regression. I running the example. this is code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

def inference(X):
 W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1]), name="weights")
 b = tf.Variable(0., name="bias")
 return tf.linalg.matmul(X, W) + b
def inputs():
 weight_age = [[84, 46], [73, 20], [65, 52], [70, 30], [76, 57], [69, 25], [63, 28], [72, 36], [79,57], [75,44], [27,24], [89,31], [65,52], [57,23], [59,60], [69,48], [60,34], [79,51], [75,50], [82,34], [59,46], [67,23], [85,37], [55, 40], [63,30]]
 blood_fat_content = [354, 190, 405, 263, 451, 302, 288, 385, 402, 365, 209, 290, 346, 254, 395, 434, 220, 374, 308, 220, 311, 181, 274, 303, 244]
 return tf.compat.v1.to_float(weight_age), tf.compat.v1.to_float(blood_fat_content)
def train(total_loss):
 learning_rate = 0.0000001
 return tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(total_loss)
def evaluate(sess, X, Y):
 print(sess.run(inference([[80., 25.]])))
 print(sess.run(inference([[65., 25.]])))
def loss(X, Y):
 Y_predicted = inference(X)
 return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.squared_difference(Y_predicted, Y))

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  tf.compat.v1.initialize_all_variables().run()
  X, Y = inputs()
  total_loss = loss(X, Y)
  train_op = train(total_loss)
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.compat.v1.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
  # actual training loop
  training_steps = 1000
  for step in range(training_steps):
   sess.run([train_op])
   # for debugging and learning purposes, see how the loss gets decremented thru training steps
   if step % 10 == 0:
    print("loss: ", sess.run([total_loss]))
  evaluate(sess, X, Y)
  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
  sess.close()
```

I try to run it and i receive this problem:
something wrong with  `sess.run([train_op])`

> WARNING:tensorflow:`tf.train.start_queue_runners()` was called when no queue runners were defined. You can safely remove the call to this deprecated function.
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
> 1374     try:
> -> 1375       return fn(*args)
> 1376     except errors.OpError as e:

```
6 frames
FailedPreconditionError: Could not find variable weights_15. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status=Not found: Resource localhost/weights_15/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node MatMul_17/ReadVariableOp}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1392                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1393                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1394       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
   1395 
   1396   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Could not find variable weights_15. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status=Not found: Resource localhost/weights_15/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[node MatMul_17/ReadVariableOp (defined at <ipython-input-20-ba8b6c1518ea>:7) ]]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node MatMul_17/ReadVariableOp:
 weights_15 (defined at <ipython-input-20-ba8b6c1518ea>:5)

Original stack trace for 'MatMul_17/ReadVariableOp':
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 448, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 477, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 431, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-20-ba8b6c1518ea>", line 25, in <module>
    total_loss = loss(X, Y)
  File "<ipython-input-20-ba8b6c1518ea>", line 19, in loss
    Y_predicted = inference(X)
  File "<ipython-input-20-ba8b6c1518ea>", line 7, in inference
    return tf.linalg.matmul(X, W) + b
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 3576, in matmul
    b = ops.convert_to_tensor(b, dtype_hint=a.dtype.base_dtype, name="b")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py", line 163, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1554, in convert_to_tensor
    value, dtype=preferred_dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 2023, in _dense_var_to_tensor
    return var._dense_var_to_tensor(dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 1421, in _dense_var_to_tensor
    return self.value()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 576, in value
    return self._read_variable_op()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 683, in _read_variable_op
    result = read_and_set_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 674, in read_and_set_handle
    self.handle, self._dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_resource_variable_ops.py", line 485, in read_variable_op
    "ReadVariableOp", resource=resource, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 750, in _apply_op_helper
    attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3569, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2045, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack_for_node(self._c_op)
```

***Can anyone help me ? Any help is appreciated.***

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but the suggested practice is to define the graph outside the scope of the session (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Variable).

Also, if you are using TF2, you need to disable eager execution with

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```